# The purpose of JUnit test?

Tags: eclipse, junit, jar

In order to create a properly running JAR file from my Eclipse project, does the JUnit test of the project have to be without any errors and failures? Or it is not neccessary?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is necessary! Your JUnit tests should build and pass green before you build the JAR.

If not, then something was wrong ;)

Technically speaking, there may be a way to disable or ignore tests when you build your JAR, but I wouldn't recommend it. Tests are there for a reason...

Answer (score 0):

Running or 'green' unit tests only means the code does what your unit tests are checking. This doesn't mean you code is correct, as it could still have errors that you have not detected or even one of your unit tests may be wrong.

Typically, creating a JAR file from you code does not require all unit tests to be successfully running, because these two tasks are independent of each other.

If you are releasing you software, however, you might want to show you clients how good your software is. Unit testing is a good way to improve the quality of your software, while it is by no means the ultimate proof.

Answer (score 0):

Well, ideally your unit tests should check whether your code is working correctly. This in turn means that you won't have a "properly running JAR file" if the tests are failing.

I'm writing "ideally" because it is entirely possible to have tests checking irrelevant and / or obsolete functionality. In that case your tests are broken and you typically have no idea whether you have a "properly running" application.